# Responding to a phone book access request programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on a test application that is going to be used for automated bluetooth device testing.  My application basically connects a phone to a Bluetooth device so that the device can be tested with an Android device, the nature of the testing isn't relevant to this question really.

My issue is, one of the Bluetooth devices I am working with has voice prompts that will speak the name of your phone contact when getting an incoming call from them.  In order to do this the Bluetooth device needs access to the Android's phone book.  So the first time the device connects, I get a dialog message that pops up with a Phone book access request, saying the device is requesting access to contacts and call history.  I am trying to find a way to respond to this request inside of the test application, the idea of this application is that it is supposed to be automated, so I don't want to have to have somebody come by the phone and click yes to this request, but I definitely need to respond yes or else the voice prompts won't work properly.

I am able to find when the request pops up using the onWindowFocusChanged function, and I confirmed using the debugger that this function is called when the request pops up.  At first I thought maybe I could dismiss it with ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS, but as it turns out this won't work, and even if it did dismiss the dialog (and it doesn't dismiss it), according to the documentation this Intent only requests that a dialog is dismissed and ultimately the dialog will decide how it wants to handle that.

```
//This function will be called when the dialog is shown.
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean isTrue) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(isTrue);
    if (!isTrue) {
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        this.sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

Dismissing it isn't really what I wanted to accomplish anyways because I want to be able to chose the yes option so my device gets access to the contacts properly.  My other idea, which is sort of a hack would be to just figure out where on the screen the notification is located and inject a touch event at the location of the yes option.  This is not really how I want to do it because I would have to basically figure out the location with trial and error because I don't believe I can get access to the dialog from inside an app to figure out it's exact location.  Also it would constrain me to only being able to use whatever specific devices I took the time to find the coordinates of the yes button.

Any ideas?